# Discord.js (Upload a Attachmend also Image and get the URL of This attchemend directly)

Tags: discord.js

I need help.

I want to upload an Image in Discord and after finished upload, I will post it automaticly in an embed.
its this possible?

Comment: so i will post it in `.setImage('xxxxxx')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use an attachment in a rich embed without having to send the attachment separately.

1. Create an attachment using the [Attachment](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Attachment) class constructor. You can use a Buffer, local path, URL, or Stream to generate the file.
2. Construct your [RichEmbed](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RichEmbed) as usual. Attachments can be referred to within an embed with this syntax: `attachment://<filename>`.
3. By utilizing the `options` parameter of [`TextBasedChannel.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send), you can send both attachments *and* embeds.

Consider the following code which sends a rich embed with Discord's logo as the image...

```js
const { Attachment, RichEmbed } = require('discord.js');

const attachment = new Attachment('https://discordapp.com/assets/fc0b01fe10a0b8c602fb0106d8189d9b.png', 'Discord.png');
const files = [attachment];

const embed = new RichEmbed()
  .setColor('#7289DA')
  .setImage('attachment://Discord.png');

/* TextBasedChannel */.send({ embed, files })
  .catch(console.error);
```